# param is missing or the value is empty: activity Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When i try to create an entry in my application i get

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in TodosController#create
param is missing or the value is empty: activity
```

Expected Source:

```
def todo_params
    params.require(:activity).permit(:name, :due)
end
```

Here is my request:

```
    {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"mR11T50dN8tm/q+S0fNd+mYYZBR6Xq4it4ujtEOmt/7RmA4TjzTKD//XmFU+UumpbmKcaj9DtG6noHOD2pwk2w==",
 "todo"=>{"name"=>"Ezekiel",
 "activity"=>"test....an 8th time"},
 "commit"=>"Create Todo"}
```

I am not sure why this is not working as the activity parameter is clearly passed through as it is in the request

Here is the controller:

```
def create
    @todo = Todo.create(todo_params)
end

def todo_params
    params.require(:activity).permit(:name, :due)
end
```

And finally my View:

```
<div class="reveal" id="ezekielTask" data-reveal>
    <%= simple_form_for @todo do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :name, :as => :hidden, :input_html => {:value => "Ezekiel"} %>
        <%= f.input :activity %>
        <%= f.button :submit %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

This part of my rails application is a todo list, it displays fine, i can add entries through the console, this way just will not work and i have no idea why. it is passing the data correctly just not accepting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller

```
def create
        @todo = Todo.create(todo_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if  @todo.save
            format.html { redirect_to location_path, notice: 'Todo was successfully created.' }

          else
            format.html { render :new }
           }
          end
        end
      end
```

Params

```
def todo_params
  params.require(:todo).permit(:name, :activity)
end
```

Comment: This worked. Can you explain what it did and why it fixed it?

Comment: Of course, sorry for not explaining before, what I did was that in the function of creating always you must know whether or not this is done by setting the condition if @ variable.save and thus redirigineod the view you want if you saved or if it did not show the errors another thing that was doing badly and as you see in the questions below is that the parameters require an array called everything that contains: name,: activity, what does this is that it allows that array to contain them and so you can handle them

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the strong params method to require `todo` and then accept the `:name` and `:activity` params

```
def todo_params
  params.require(:todo).permit(:name, :activity)
end
```

The reason for that is

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"mR11T50dN8tm/q+S0fNd+mYYZBR6Xq4it4ujtEOmt/7RmA4TjzTKD//XmFU+UumpbmKcaj9DtG6noHOD2pwk2w==",
 "todo"=>{"name"=>"Ezekiel",
 "activity"=>"test....an 8th time"},
 "commit"=>"Create Todo"}
```

If you see in the params you are receiving `name` and `activity` inside `todo`

Comment: I tried that, when i do that it doesnt give this error but activity comes out as nil

Comment: I can see the value for activity in params so it should create unless the operation is rolling back

Comment: try debugging and see if there is any error inn the object before saving

Answer (score 1):

In the `require` parameter normaly we use the name of the model (`todo`) and inside `permit` we use the attributes of that model (`:name, :activity`)

```
def todo_params
    params.require(:todo).permit(:name, :activity)
end
```